# About the group law on the extended square class group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

> We define a group law on the set
>   $$
>   Q(K) := \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times K^\bullet/K^{\bullet 2}
> $$
>   as follows
>   \begin{align*}
>   (0, \alpha) + (0, \beta) &= (0, \alpha \beta) \\
>   (1, \alpha) + (0, \beta) &= (1, \alpha \beta) \\
>   (1, \alpha) + (1, \beta) &= (0, -\alpha \beta).
> \end{align*}
>   It is trivial to check that, in fact, this satisfies the axioms of an abelian group.
>   $Q(K)$ is called the *extended square class group*.
>   Next, one checks equally trivially that
>   $$
>   (e,d) \colon W(K) \to Q(K)
> $$
>   is a group homomorphism.
>   Thus, $e$ and $d$ together yield a reasonable invariant.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmXyj.png).)

This is excerpt from W. Scharlau: *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms,*
[page 37](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA36).

In this $Q(K)$ we define group law as given I don't understand what is third law saying $(1,\alpha) + (1,\beta) = (0,-\alpha\beta)$ is fine in first coordinate since it is from two element group but why $-\alpha \beta$ in second coordinate. Also how it satisfy abelian axioms? What I think is since both groups are abelian there cartesian product is also abelian. And last question is how to show it is homomorphisam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group containing an element $g$ of the center of $G$.
Let us define a law on the set $K = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times G$ by setting
\begin{align}
(0,x)(0,y) &= (0,xy) \\
(0,x)(1,y) &= (1,xy) \\
(1,x)(0,y) &= (1,xy) \\
(1,x)(1,y) &= (0,gxy)
\end{align}
I claim that $K$ is a group for this law. To check associativity, one needs to compare
$A = \bigl((a,x)(b,y)\bigr)(c,z)$ and $B = (a,x)\bigl((b,y)(c,z)\bigr)$. The only nontrivial case occur when at least two elements of the set $\{a, b, c\}$ are equal to $1$. Now, 
\begin{align}
  \bigl((1,x)(1,y)\bigr)(0,z) &= (0,gxy)(0,z) = (0,gxyz) = (1,x)(1,yz)= (1,x)\bigl((1,y)(0,z)\bigr) \\
  \bigl((1,x)(0,y)\bigr)(1,z) &= (1,xy)(1,z) = (0,gxyz) = (1,x)(1,yz)= (1,x)\bigl((0,y)(1,z)\bigr) \\
\bigl((0,x)(1,y)\bigr)(1,z) &= (1,xy)(1,z) = (0,gxyz) = (0,x)(1,yz)= (0,x)\bigl((1,y)(1,z)\bigr) \\
\bigl((1,x)(1,y)\bigr)(1,z) &= (1,gxy)(1,z) = (1,gxyz) = (1,x)(1,yz)= (1,x)\bigl((1,y)(1,z)\bigr)
\end{align}
Clearly $(0,1)$ is the identity element, the inverse of $(0,x)$ is $(0, x^{-1})$ and the inverse of $(1,x)$ is $(1,g^{-1}x^{-1})$. Thus $K$ is a group.

For your question, just take $g = -1$.

Comment: Sorry, but since you do not define $e$ and $d$, it is not difficult to answer this part of your question...

Comment: I am afraid this is not good practice on this site. Your question should be self-contained and should avoid including photos of page books. Links to books on Google should be given for reference, not for a crucial definition (you can refer to wikipedia, though). Think of the people answering your questions. It makes things much easier if it is possible to copy and paste your question in the answer.